# Homepage White Screen when not logged in

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem. When I go to the homepage of my wordpress website I have a white screen. When I log in and go to the homepage I can see my homepage. All other pages are also working when not logged in. (Example: site.com/blabla)

Comment: Is there anything on the logs?

Comment: Have you tried another (default) theme? Same behaviour?